# Angularjs with typescript - Navigate to URL and to get parameter query string

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a login page, when credentials not correct, i need to return to the same page to get a environment variable (of query string):

```
if (login==false) {
vm.$rootRouter.navigateByUrl('/login?fail=ko');
}
```

When I call the URL "/login", i am going to another component view1ViewComp:

```
this.$routeConfig = [
{
path: '/login',
name: 'View1',
component: 'view1ViewComp'
}
```

And this controller (View1ViewCtrl) must get the variable value  "?fail=ko" in the constructor method:

```
vm.fail = this.getParURL('fail');
```

But the value "vm.fail" is empty.

```
Function getParULR:

    getParURL(name) {
      let regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
      let regex = new RegExp(regexS);
      let tmpURL = window.location.href;
      let results = regex.exec(tmpURL);

      if (results == null) {
        return "";
      }
      else {
        return results[1];
      }
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `getParURL`? Why navigate to the same page with an additional query parameter instead of simply staying on the page and, for example, change the state of the controller to display an error message?

Comment: getParURL is a function for to get the variables in a query string url. The design of the application was done, the html template of component View1ViewComp it loads the login component .

Comment: <login-comp err-login="{{view1ViewCtrl.fail}}"></login-comp>

Comment: Oh my! You really need to learn the principle of a single page application. And to stop reinventing the wheel. Use the angular $location service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search. Or your router params service which, I guess, also supports that.

Comment: Yes I know, is  not good practice, only need one component, thank you for your advices.